# Ember-data - Get the hash of the Model

Tags: ember-data

This is probably a frequently asked question but how do I get the opaque hash from an Ember.Data model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your version of Ember at them moment. There have been a lot of changes lately, but it should be one of these 3 methods:

```
object = App.MyModel.find(1)


object.toString()
object.toData()
object.serialize() //latest version
```